# How to count pipes in first line of text using DOS batch (CMD)

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe, file-management

I have an input text file similar to the following:

```
a|b|c|d|e
1|2|3|4|5
6|7|8|9|10
```

I want to count the number of pipes (`|`) in the first line.

Expected output: `4`.

I am restricted to use just the batch script. PowerShell is not an option.

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: Can you use AWK: `awk -F'|' 'NR==1{print NF-1}'`?

Comment: Hey, thank you for your response. I need to get this done using windows batch script.

Comment: I see, you updated the title from `bash` to `batch`. Are you sure you can't call AWK? Have a look at this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41960019/7659430) on Stackoverflow, you might find some inspiration there.

Comment: Bash or Batch? In bash this is: `while read name; do grep -o "|" <<< "${name}" | wc -l; done < file.txt`

Comment: If in Windows, is PowerShell an option?

Comment: In Powershell you can do: `(Get-Content c:\folder\input.txt -First 1 | Select-String -Pattern '\|' -AllMatches).Matches.Count`. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45728463/7659430) on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Powershell seems to be so much fun, it even uses `$_` like `Perl`! It's unfortunate I never had time to learn how to do everything all over again.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I am restricted to use just the batch script. PowerShell is not an option.

To clarify again, I am looking for a solution in a batch script (not bash). Apologies for the misspelled title earlier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pure bat to do this job:

```cmd
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f %%i in (.\input.txt)do set "_line=%%i"&& (
     for %%p in ("!_line:|=" "!")do set /a "_cnt+=1")&& set/a "_cnt-=1"& echo/!_cnt! & goto:nxt
    )

:nxt
```

---

**Update:**
I just trying to use the matching **[@mael'](https://superuser.com/users/952586/mael)** solution with my, or, I just trying to use my solution with the **[@mael'](https://superuser.com/users/952586/mael)** solution, anyway, English hard to me explain..

---

```cmd
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f %%i in (.\input.txt)do (
     set "_line=%%i"&& (for %%p in ("!_line:|=" "!")do set /a "_cnt+=1")&& set/a "_cnt-=1"& goto:next
    )

:next
echo/ !_cnt!
```

---

Answer (score 2):

Alternative method:

```
@echo off

set "src=C:\location\of\text\file.txt"

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /p line=<"%src%"

set "count=-1"
for %%a in ("%line:|=" "%") do set /A count+=1

echo %count%
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

- let [`set /P`](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html) read the first line of the text file, say `input.txt` (which is expected to be shorter than 1024 characters or bytes, including the terminating line-break);
- [`echo`](https://ss64.com/nt/echo.html) the read first line but as Unicode text, which is established by initiating a new [`cmd`](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) instance using by the `/U` option; this basically inserts null-bytes after each single character;
- let the [`find` command](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html) do the job of counting, which interprets null-bytes just like line-breaks, so it receives lines of single characters (like `a`, `|`, `b`, `|`, `c`, `|`, `d`, `|`, `e`, with respect to your sample);

Here is am example code:

```cmd
set "CNT=0" & for /F %%C in ('
    ^< "input.txt" set /P LINE=^& cmd /U /V /C echo(!LINE!^| find /C "|"
') do set "CNT=%%C"
echo(%CNT%
```

With your sample input file, this script would return:

> ```cmd
> 4
> ```